# Stretched background layout using Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm working on converting a layout to HTML/CSS using Bootstrap 3.

My question is, how can I implement the following layout in Bootstrap such that the parts highlighted in rectangles only show up in screen sizes with width 1000+ pixels? When screen sizes are below 1000px, I want the parts in the rectangles hidden.

Of particular difficulty seems the navigation bar. What do you folks suggest?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well there are couple of ways to do this.

**NOTE:** I am just going to give an idea, NOT the whole solution.

1) You can have two `div`s like

**HTML**

```
<div class="firstDiv" />
<img />
<div class="secDiv" />
```

**CSS**

```
.firstDiv {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   width: 20%;
   opacity: 0;
}

.secDiv {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   width: 20%;
   opacity: 0;
}

@media(max-screen: 1000px) {
   .firstDiv .secDiv {
      opacity: 1;
   }
}
```

2) You can make two images (one is full and other is croped) and set the background like

**HTML**

```
<div class="myImage" />
```

**CSS**

```
.myImage {
   background-image: url('/path/to/fullimage.png');
}

@media(max-screen: 1000px) {
   .myImage {
      background-image: url('/path/to/croppedimage.png');
   }
}
```